# LG E1942C-BN monitor refuses to enable white balance

Tags: display

I got this monitor the other day, and it refuses to enable "white balance" in the settings. If I try to toggle it from 'no' to 'yes', it just reverts back to 'no' a second later. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by realising that even though there is a yes/no option on the white balance setting, it's not a toggle. I failed to notice that it simply makes the screen redo the white balance, was too focused on watching that value stay on 'yes'.

Comment: I have a Flatron w2042s that when I change the white balance to YES, you can tell that it tries to fix the image, it even manages to see perfect, but at the last second it returns as it was and changes to NO again

Comment: forget it, the problem was that I had the "night light" option activated in windows.